# Fastest way to determine the range of the same type neighbors in a dataframe column

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, pandas

What is the fastest way of getting the range of the same type neighbors in a `PANDAS` dataframe?
the problem is i have a dataframe that is sorted in `input` column and i need to know the range of these values that value of column `output` is the same near each other.

**What i did?**
i wrote a programm that dose what i need :

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
print("Original Data:")
print(data)
tmpdata = data.copy()
slicedorg = data.copy()
jump = 0
to = 0
while jump < len(data):
    tmpdata['output'] = (slicedorg['output'] == slicedorg['output'].loc[0])
    jump += to
    try:
        to = tmpdata['output'].tolist().index(False)
        if jump == 0:
            data['input'] = data['input'].replace([data['input'].loc[range(jump, to + jump)]] 
                                                                    , "(begin," + str(data['input'].loc[jump + to]) + ")" )
        else:
            data['input'] = data['input'].replace([data['input'].loc[range(jump, to + jump)]] 
                                                                    , "[" + str(data['input'].loc[jump]) + "," 
                                                                        + str(data['input'].loc[jump + to]) + ")")
        tmpdata = tmpdata.tail(len(tmpdata) - to)
        slicedorg = slicedorg.tail(len(slicedorg) - to)
        tmpdata = tmpdata.reset_index(drop=True)
        slicedorg = slicedorg.reset_index(drop=True)
    except:
        data['input'] = data['input'].replace([slicedorg['input'].loc[range(0, len(data))]] 
                                                                , "[" + str(tmpdata['input'].loc[0]) + ",end)")
        break
print("\nAfter Altering:")
print(data)
```

the result of this pice of code is like that :

```
Original Data:
      input output
0       3   gear
1       7   gear
2      11   gear
3      24   gear
4      55   back
5      56   back
6      82   back
7     100   gear
8     101   gear
9     200   peak
10    208   peak
11    233   peak

After Altering:
         input output
0   (begin,55)   gear
1   (begin,55)   gear
2   (begin,55)   gear
3   (begin,55)   gear
4     [55,100)   back
5     [55,100)   back
6     [55,100)   back
7    [100,200)   gear
8    [100,200)   gear
9    [200,end)   peak
10   [200,end)   peak
11   [200,end)   peak
```

how ever even this code is works for me but my data table is very very huge and making two copy of data and loop through the columns are very time consuming, is there a better way of doing what i want? note that maybe I didn't wrote a very good code (I'm sort of new in python) but I'm mostly looking for suggested algorithm that is faster.

I'm using python 3.5 and latest version of pandas.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm too lazy to get the formatting exactly the way you want, but you can do the hard part using the compare-cumsum-groupby pattern:

```
group_ids = (df["output"] != df["output"].shift()).cumsum()
grouped = df["input"].groupby(group_ids)
bounds = grouped.min().shift(-1)

left = bounds.shift(1).fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)
right = bounds.fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str)

left.iloc[0] = "begin"
right.iloc[-1] = "end"
bounds = left + "," + right

df["bounds"] = bounds.loc[group_ids].values
```

gives me

```
>>> df
    input output    bounds
0       3   gear  begin,55
1       7   gear  begin,55
2      11   gear  begin,55
3      24   gear  begin,55
4      55   back    55,100
5      56   back    55,100
6      82   back    55,100
7     100   gear   100,200
8     101   gear   100,200
9     200   peak   200,end
10    208   peak   200,end
11    233   peak   200,end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer @DSM, but can you explain exactly what your code is doing line by line?